# Android - Can Android app make a like facebook post action?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm currently researching facebook sdk.

I have googled around and just found some tutorial with like button for pages and haven't seen any tutorial for like button for posts.
So does facebook sdk 4.+ allow us to make an action like post?

If it does, can you guys show me some example please?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes it is possible just see the Facebook doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all written in the documentation:

> Note: as of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I have read the document and the action like post is now restricted that it's only available for page access token. 
So is there anyway that I can like as my profile not my page?

Comment: @ChâuMinhPhúc Guess it's not possible then. I am not using facebook, but i heard a lot of the possibility to buy likes. Maybe that's a reason they disabled it.